# elrepo archive metadata doesn't list kernel-lt as of 2018-10-01 0600 UTC

Tags: centos, artifactory, yum

Anyone seeing problems with the elrepo archive mirrors not able to install or list all available kernels?

```
    yum list available --showduplicates \
    --disablerepo=* --enablerepo elrepo-amirror-kernel kernel-lt
```

Prior to 10 am today / 6 am UTC our artifactory instance could report multiple kernel-lt packages.  After whether I use artifactory or go directly to the remote repository I see nothing:

```
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "presto" plugin
Running "config" handler for "presto" plugin
Config time: 0.018
Running "init" handler for "fastestmirror" plugin
Yum Version: 3.2.29
COMMAND: yum list available --showduplicates --disablerepo=* --enablerepo elrepo-amirror-kernel kernel*
Installroot: /
Ext Commands:

   available
   kernel*
Reading Local RPMDB
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Package Sacks
Running "postreposetup" handler for "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
pkgsack time: 0.003
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

### Repo definition

```
[elrepo-amirror-kernel]
name=ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Kernel Repository - el6
baseurl=http://lon.mirror.rackspace.com/elrepo/archive/kernel/el6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
protect=0
```

### Mirrors Tested

- http://mirrors.coreix.net/elrepo-archive-archive
- http://lon.mirror.rackspace.com/elrepo/archive/kernel

Direct access to repos fails, so it cannot be artifactory.

The following had no impact:

- clean all, makecache
- `rm -rf /var/cache/yum/` and makecache

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may have been a problem with our artifactory instance but this problem above was caused by an exclude for kernels to avoid automatically changing kernel upon reboot.

Adding `--disableexcludes=all` to the line allow us to see the kernel-lt packages.